# Was it really Frigga talking to Loki?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-the-dark-world

Both Loki and and Frigga have similar powers in creating illusions, so when Loki was locked up in the dungeon in *Thor: The Dark World*, was it Frigga creating an illusion of herself to speak with Loki? or was Loki creating an illusion of her?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> was it Frigga creating an illusion of herself to speak with Loki

Well, yes.

When Loki was in dungeon, nobody was allowed to visit him. That's why she created an illusion to talk with him.

You can see it in a [video of deleted scene](https://youtu.be/OJbtRuNgnIA?list=PLnX89JOgn4GkgBqPCl-QOd7pkq8GStxe-) on [this page](https://www.tor.com/2014/01/29/thor-and-frigga-discuss-their-loki-problem-in-deleted-scene-from-thor-the-dark-world/). In this scene, Frigga was talking with him through some sort of fire and Loki sees it like his mother came to visit him.

Later in the movie Frigga creates the same sort of holographic image

> of Jane Foster.